# cuPrintf problem

Tags: c, gpu, cuda

I am trying to copy a struct array to device.I am working with one GPU atm, and i have a problem with cuPrintf function which i use to debug my code.

My struct definition is as below:

```
 struct Node
 {
        char Key[25];
        char ConsAlterKey[25];
        char MasterKey[3];
        int VowelDeletion;
        char Data[6];
        char MasterData[6];
        int Children[35];
        int ChildCount;
 };
```

and for test purpose i fill the struct array like this :

```
void FillArray(Node *NodeArray)
{       
    for(int i=0;i<TotalNodeCount;i++)
    {
            strcpy(NodeArray[i].Key,"Key");

            strcpy(NodeArray[i].ConsAlterKey,"ConsAlterKey");

            strcpy(NodeArray[i].MasterKey,"Mk");

            NodeArray[i].VowelDeletion=0;

            strcpy(NodeArray[i].Data,"Data");

            strcpy(NodeArray[i].MasterData,"Mdata");

            NodeArray[i].ChildCount=5;

            for(int j =0;j<NodeArray[i].ChildCount;j++)
            {
                    NodeArray[i].Children[j]=i+j;
            }
    }
}
```

my main function looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    Node *NodeArray;
    Node *GpuTree;
    int tokenCount=0;
    int *tokenCountGPU;

    NodeArray =(Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)*(TotalNodeCount));
    FillArray(NodeArray);
    printf("Filling test : %s\n", NodeArray[13].Key);

    gpuAssert(cudaMalloc( (void**)&GpuTree, sizeof(Node)*(TotalNodeCount)));
    gpuAssert(cudaMemcpy(GpuTree, NodeArray,sizeof(Node)*(TotalNodeCount), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    //test value
    tokenCount=35;


    gpuAssert( cudaMalloc((void **)&tokenCountGPU, sizeof(int)) );
    gpuAssert( cudaMemcpy(tokenCountGPU, &tokenCount, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );

    cudaPrintfInit();
    Test <<< 1, tokenCount >>> (GpuTree,tokenCountGPU);
    cudaPrintfDisplay(stdout, true);
    cudaPrintfEnd();
    gpuAssert( cudaGetLastError() );

    //TODO:free pointers
    return(0);
}
```

and if I write test function as below:

```
__global__ void Test(Node *Trie,int *tokenCount)
{
    if (threadIdx.x < *tokenCount) 
    {
            cuPrintf("%s\n",Trie[threadIdx.x].Key);

    }   
    return;
}
```

i get output like this:

```
Filling test : Key
[0, 0]: <
[0, 1]: ¶☺!
[0, 2]: ì☺!
[0, 3]: Ä☻!
[0, 4]: o♥!
[0, 5]: t♦!
[0, 6]: L♣!
[0, 7]: $♠!
[0, 8]: ü♠!
[0, 9]: Ô!
[0, 10]: !
[0, 11]: "
[0, 12]: \
!
[0, 13]: 4♂!
[0, 14]: ♀♀!
[0, 15]: ä♀!
!0, 16]: ¼
[0, 17]: "♫!
[0, 18]: l☼!
[0, 19]: D►!
[0, 20]: ∟◄!
[0, 21]: ô◄!
[0, 22]: Ì↕!
[0, 23]: ¤‼!
[0, 24]: |¶!
[0, 25]: T§!
[0, 26]: ,▬!
[0, 27]: ♦↨!
[0, 28]: Ü↨!
[0, 29]: ´↑!
[0, 30]: O↓!
[0, 31]: d→!
[0, 32]: <←!
[0, 33]: ¶∟!
[0, 34]: ì∟!
```

but if i change my test method to this:

```
__global__ void Test(Node *Trie,int *tokenCount)
{
    if (threadIdx.x < *tokenCount) 
    {
        cuPrintf("%c%c%c\n",
                            Trie[threadIdx.x].Key[0],
                            Trie[threadIdx.x].Key[1],
                            Trie[threadIdx.x].Key[2]);
    }
    return;
}
```

then i get the correct output:

```
Filling test : Key
[0, 0]: Key
[0, 1]: Key
[0, 2]: Key
[0, 3]: Key
[0, 4]: Key
[0, 5]: Key
[0, 6]: Key
[0, 7]: Key
[0, 8]: Key
[0, 9]: Key
[0, 10]: Key
[0, 11]: Key
[0, 12]: Key
[0, 13]: Key
[0, 14]: Key
[0, 15]: Key
[0, 16]: Key
[0, 17]: Key
[0, 18]: Key
[0, 19]: Key
[0, 20]: Key
[0, 21]: Key
[0, 22]: Key
[0, 23]: Key
[0, 24]: Key
[0, 25]: Key
[0, 26]: Key
[0, 27]: Key
[0, 28]: Key
[0, 29]: Key
[0, 30]: Key
[0, 31]: Key
[0, 32]: Key
[0, 33]: Key
[0, 34]: Key
```

So the question is why do i get corrupt output when I try to print strings through using "%s"?

---

So the problem is solved.Looks like it is because of cuPrintf limitations. And actually i was not aware of them.Thank you.

Here is a small test:

```
__global__ void Test(Node *Trie,int *tokenCount)
{
    const char *Key="Key";
    char *KeyPointer="Key";
    char KeyArray[4]="Key";
    cuPrintf("Constant : %s - Array :%s  - Pointer : %s - Casting Pointer : %s - Casting Array : %s\n",Key, KeyArray,KeyPointer,(const char *)KeyPointer,(const char *)KeyArray);

    //cuPrintf("%s\n",Trie[threadIdx.x].Key);
    //cuPrintf("%d\n",*tokenCount);

}
```

Gives the output :

```
    [0, 0]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 1]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 2]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 3]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 4]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 5]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 6]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 7]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 8]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 9]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 10]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 11]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 12]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 13]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 14]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 15]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 16]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 17]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 18]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 19]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 20]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 21]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 22]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 23]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 24]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 25]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 26]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 27]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 28]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 29]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 30]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 31]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 32]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 33]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
    [0, 34]: Constant : Key - Array :  - Pointer : ♀ - Casting Pointer : Key - Casting Array : Key
```

Comment: What kind of GPU are you using? And what is TotalNodeCount set to?

Comment: @meva: ok for this test but now, what if you cast `keyPointer` to a `(const char*)` within call to `cuPrintf`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at `cuPrintf` documentation (a readme is located at **C/src/simplePrintf/doc/cuPrintf_readme.htm** from the base directory where you installed the SDK):

There are Limitations/Known Issues on the usage of `cuPrintf`, number 2 answers your question:

> Limitations / Known Issues
>
> Currently, the following limitations
>   and restrictions apply to cuPrintf:
>
> 1. Buffer size is rounded up to the nearest factor of 256
> 2. **Arguments associated with “%s” string format specifiers must be of**
>         **type (const char** *)
> 3. To print the value of a (const char *) pointer, it must first be
>      converted to (char *). All (const char
>      *) arguments are interpreted as strings
> 4. Non-zero return code does not match standard C printf()
> 5. Cannot asynchronously output the printf buffer (i.e. while kernel is
>      running)
> 6. Calling cudaPrintfDisplay implicitly issues a
>      cudaDeviceSynchronize()
> 7. Restrictions applied by cuPrintfRestrict persist between
>      launches. To clear these from the
>      host-side, you must call
>      cudaPrintfEnd() then cudaPrintfInit()
>      again
> 8. cuPrintf output is undefined if multiple modules are loaded into a
>      single context
> 9. Compile with “-arch=sm_11” or better when possible. Buffer usage is
>      far more efficient and register use is
>      lower
> 10. Supported format specifiers are: “cdiouxXeEfgGaAs”
> 11. Behaviour of format specifiers, especially justification/size
>       specifiers, are dependent on the host
>       machine’s implementation of printf
> 12. cuPrintf requires applications to be built using the CUDA runtime API

In your case you're not using `const char*` arguments.

Comment: Thanks! - I was banging my head against a wall -- it appeared to be correct, but the standard printf syntax isn't fully supported.

Comment: @M. Tibbits: I just checked the implementation and it seems a bit raw :) It would be interesting for OP to test with casts or rewrite the function to accept char*

Comment: It would be.  I'm personally in a time crunch on another project -- hence I offered the bounty and 'paused' my effort.

Answer (score 1):

On your most recent update, you need to multiple slenz by `sizeof(char)` <- when you're copying.  So it should be:

```
gpuAssert( cudaMemcpy(strGPU, str, slenz*sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

Comment: How about printing out the `childCount`?  Is the gpu able to pull an integer out of the structure?  For the record, this all seems bizarre.  I don't see any problems in your code above.  **Oh, and, could you print out `sizeof(Node)`**?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer.Sizeof(Node) is 216.

Comment: And i have updated the code as you say still getting nothing.Maybe my version of cuPrintf.cu has a problem.Anyway i dont want to bother you with this newbie question because i have solved the problem in my code and i dont need cuPrintf for now.In fact i will post a new question about performance guidance for my current code.I hope you will help me on that :)

Comment: So I had just suggested using `printf`s in the kernel until I realized you need a device with compute capability 2.x (Fermi).  Crap.  Back to drawing boards...

Comment: I find that I learn more when things don't work... I'm still stuck on why the above code doesn't produce the expected results -- hence the bounty -- let's attract better minds!

Comment: Ah :) I'm just trying to do a simple project.Kind of an enhanced patricia trie.Thank you.

Comment: And here are the codes if anyone want to run it.http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13011034/codes.zip

Answer (score 1):

One of the members of your struct is

```
    char MasterKey[3];
```

and when you initialize the objects you do

```
        //strcpy(NodeArray[i].MasterKey,"MasterKey");
        strcpy(NodeArray[i].MasterKey,"Msk"); /* still too large */
```

which is a little (!) too much for the available space.

Comment: Now it's MasterData[6]: `strcpy(NodeArray[i].MasterData,"Master");`. What happens, assuming `cuPrintf` behaves the same as `printf`, if you limit the output to 3 characters: `cuPrintf("%3.3s\n", Trie[threadIdx.x].Key)`

Comment: Done but i still get corrupt output with `cuPrintf("%3.3s\n", Trie[threadIdx.x].Key);`