# How do we use cuPrintf()?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

What do we have to do to use cuPrintf()? (device compute capability 1.2, Ubuntu 12) I couldn't find "cuPrintf.cu" and "cudaPrintf.cuh", so i downloaded their code and include them:

```
#include "cuPrintf.cuh"
#include "cuPrintf.cu"
```

By the way this is the rest of the code:

```
__global__ void hello_kernel (float f) {
printf ("Thread number %d. f = %d\n", threadIdx.x, f);
}

    int main () {
    dim3 gridSize = dim3 (1);
    dim3 blockSize = dim3 (16);
    cudaPrintfInit ();
    hello_kernel <<< gridSize, blockSize >>> (1.2345f);
    cudaPrintfDisplay (stdout, true);
    cudaPrintfEnd ();
    return (0);
}
```

But nvcc still gives a mistake:

```
max@max-Lenovo-G560:~/CUDA/matrixMult$ nvcc printfTest.cu -o printfTest

printfTest.cu(5): error: calling a __host__ function("printf") from a __global__
function("hello_kernel") is not allowed
```

Thanks!

Comment: call `cuPrintf` in your kernel not `printf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your kernel instead of this:

```
printf ("Thread number %d. f = %d\n", threadIdx.x, f);
```

you should do this:

```
cuPrintf ("Thread number %d. f = %d\n", threadIdx.x, f);
```

Other than that, I believe your code is correct (it works for me).

This [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557051/cuprintf-problem) gives more tips about using cuPrintf properly.

Comment: Oops! First I tried to use printf(), but then found out that compute capability is lower than 2.0. Finally I forgot to change printf() to cuPrintf(). Sorry for stupid question :(

Answer (score -1):

Include `<stdio.h>` and compile with `-arch=sm_20`.

**Details**:

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
__global__ void hello_kernel (float f) {
    printf ("Thread number %d. f = %d\n", threadIdx.x, f);
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

compilations:

```
 nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o printfTest printfTest.cu
```

Comment: That is kernel printf, not cuPrintf

Comment: Oops! I missed the compute capability.