# 2d char array to CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpu

I need help with transfer char[][] to Cuda kernel. This is my code:

```
__global__ 
void kernel(char** BiExponent){
  for(int i=0; i<500; i++)
     printf("%c",BiExponent[1][i]); // I want print line 1
}

int main(){
  char (*Bi2dChar)[500] = new char [5000][500];
  char **dev_Bi2dChar;

  ...//HERE I INPUT DATA TO Bi2dChar

  size_t host_orig_pitch = 500 * sizeof(char);
  size_t pitch;
  cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dev_Bi2dChar, &pitch, 500 * sizeof(char), 5000);
  cudaMemcpy2D(dev_Bi2dChar, pitch, Bi2dChar, host_orig_pitch, 500 * sizeof(char), 5000, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  kernel <<< 1, 512 >>> (dev_Bi2dChar);
  free(Bi2dChar); cudaFree(dev_Bi2dChar);
}
```

I use:
nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cudaMemcpy2D` doesn't actually handle 2-dimensional (i.e. double pointer, `**`) arrays in C.
Note that the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g17f3a55e8c9aef5f90b67cdf22851375) indicates it expects single pointers, not double pointers.

Generally speaking, moving arbitrary double pointer C arrays between the host and the device is more complicated than a single pointer array.

If you really want to handle the double-pointer array, then search on "CUDA 2D Array" in the upper right hand corner of this page, and you'll find various examples of how to do it.  (For example, the answer given by @talonmies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137218/cuda-2d-array-problem))

Often, an easier approach is simply to "flatten" the array so it can be referenced by a single pointer, i.e. `char[]` instead of `char[][]`, and then use index arithmetic to simulate 2-dimensional access.

Your flattened code would look something like this:
(the code you provided is an uncompilable, incomplete snippet, so mine is also)

```
#define XDIM 5000
#define YDIM 500

__global__ 
void kernel(char* BiExponent){
  for(int i=0; i<500; i++)
     printf("%c",BiExponent[(1*XDIM)+i]); // I want print line 1
}

int main(){
  char (*Bi2dChar)[YDIM] = new char [XDIM][YDIM];
  char *dev_Bi2dChar;

  ...//HERE I INPUT DATA TO Bi2dChar

  cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_Bi2dChar,XDIM*YDIM * sizeof(char));
  cudaMemcpy(dev_Bi2dChar, &(Bi2dChar[0][0]), host_orig_pitch, XDIM*YDIM * sizeof(char), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  kernel <<< 1, 512 >>> (dev_Bi2dChar);
  free(Bi2dChar); cudaFree(dev_Bi2dChar);
}
```

If you want a pitched array, you can create it similarly, but you will still do so as single pointer arrays, not double pointer arrays.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `printf` in a Cuda kernel.  The reason being is that the code is being executed on the GPU and not on the host CPU.

You can, however use `cuPrintf`

[How do we use cuPrintf()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608287/how-do-we-use-cuprintf)

Comment: I think that `printf` work correctly. I tried `printf("Hello Cuda")`.

Comment: If you compile for architecture sm20 or newer  you can use printf directly in a kernel. This answer is basically wrong.