# How to pass string matrix to Cuda kernel from C++

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

### Problem:

I've a matrix in C++ filled with strings and I want to pass it to cuda kernel function. I know that CUDA can't handle strings so after some research I've tried out with some solutions listed below.

### Attempts:

1. define an array of pointers in C++ containing for each cell a pointer chars (for simplicity tmp[i] is filled with the strings contained into the matrix previously cited)

   *C++ section*

   > ```
   >  char *tmp[3];
   >  int text_length, array_length;
   >
   >  text_length = 4;
   >  array_length = 3;
   >
   >  tmp[0] = (char*) malloc(text_length*sizeof(char));
   >  tmp[1] = (char*) malloc(text_length*sizeof(char));
   >  tmp[2] = (char*) malloc(text_length*sizeof(char));
   >
   >  tmp[0] = "some";
   >  tmp[1] = "rand";
   >  tmp[2] = "text";
   >
   >  char *a[3];
   >  for(int i=0;i<array_length;i++)
   >  {
   >    cudaMalloc((void**) &a[i],text_length*sizeof(char));
   >    cudaMemcpy(&a[i],&tmp[i],text_length*sizeof(char),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
   >  }
   >
   >  func<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(a);
   > ```

   *CUDA section*

   > ```
   >  __global__ void func(char* a[]){
   >
   >  for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   >    printf("value[%d] = %s \n",i, a[i]);
   >  }
   > ```

   *Output*

   > ```
   >  value[0] = (null)
   >  value[1] = (null)
   >  value[2] = (null)
   > ```
2. spread the matrix filled with strings to a char pointer and pass it to cuda kernel and there try to retrieve the strings (again code simplified in C++)

   *C++ section*

   > ```
   >  char *a;
   >  int index[6];
   >
   >  a = "somerandtext";
   >  index[0] = 0; // first word start
   >  index[1] = 3; // first word end
   >  index[2] = 4; // same as first word 
   >  index[3] = 7;
   >  index[4] = 8;
   >  index[5] = 1;
   >
   >  func<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(a,index);
   > ```

   *CUDA section*

   > ```
   >  __global__ void func(char* a,int index[]){
   >
   >  int first_word_start = index[0];
   >  int first_word_end = index[1];
   >
   >  // print first word
   >  for(int i=first_word_start;i<=first_word_end;i++)
   >    printf("%c",a[i]);
   >  }
   > ```

   *Output*

   > ```
   >  no output produced
   > ```

I've tried out with a lot of other solutions but no one works for me... The problem can also re proposed asking: how can i pass 'n' strings to a cuda kernel and print (and compare) all of them there ( keep in mind that I can't pass 'n' variables).

Comment: In your first attempt, `tmp[0]` is a pointer to `char`, not an array of `char`s. Also, why are you using `cudaMalloc((void**) &a,array_length);` ? How can you assign `tmp[0] = "some"`. In general, it seems to me that your idea is using arrays of arrays of `char`s, so the answer to this post [How can I add up two 2d (pitched) arrays using nested for loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137218/how-can-i-add-up-two-2d-pitched-arrays-using-nested-for-loops) could be of interest to you.

Comment: `tmp` is an array of char*. `tmp[0]` is a char* where is allocate enough space to contain "some". I've made an error coping the code `cudaMalloc((void**) &a,array_length);`, now I edit it. Array of array is another solution that I've tried but doesn't work (for me) in cuda. Thanks.

Comment: Neither of the two code versions you have shown make any sense, and the problems have nothing to do with CUDA. I think you need to revise how pointers, arrays and strings work in C++ before you start looking at CUDA programming. Both versions will segfault in the host array setup code before you get anywhere near the GPU

Comment: I don't think I have a magic compiler because both codes work whitout segfault. The two versions are implementations of two different ways to solve my problem. Probably I need to revise how pointers and char work and for this I posted my question. If you want (and can) help me, you're welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Niether of the codes you've shown is complete, and the things you've left out may be important. You'll make it easier for others to help you if you show complete codes.  Also, anytime you're struggling with CUDA codes, it's good practice to use [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) which often times will point you at what is not working (I suspect this might have helped with your second attempt).  Also, running your code with `cuda-memcheck` is often times instructive.

In your first attempt, you've run into a classic problem with CUDA and nested pointers (`a` is a *pointer* to an array of *pointers*).  This problem occurs also pretty much any time there is a pointer buried in some other data structure.  To copy such a data structure from host to device requires a "deep copy" operation, which has multiple steps.  To understand more about this, search on "CUDA 2D array" (I consider the canonical answer to be the one given by talonmies [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137218/how-can-i-add-up-two-2d-pitched-arrays-using-nested-for-loops)) or take a look at my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431365/cudamemcpy-segmentation-fault/15435592#15435592) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459788/2d-char-array-to-cuda-kernel/19463145#19463145).

Also note that with CUDA 6, "deep copies" can be a lot easier conceptually for the programmer if you are able to use [unified memory](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-unified-memory-programming-hd).

Your second attempt appears to be headed down a path of "flattening" your 2D or pointer-to-ponter array of `char`.  That's a typical solution to the "problem" of deep-copying, resulting in less code complexity and probably also higher performance.  Here's a fully worked example, blending ideas from your first and second attempt, which seems to work for me:

```
$ cat t389.cu
#include <stdio.h>

 __global__ void func(char* a, int *indexes, int num_strings){


 for(int i=0;i<num_strings;i++){
   printf("string[%d]: ", i);
   for (int j=indexes[2*i]; j < indexes[2*i+1]; j++)
     printf("%c", a[j]);
   printf("\n");
 }
}

int main(){

 int max_text_length, num_str;
 num_str = 3;
 char *tmp[num_str];
 max_text_length = 12;

 tmp[0] = (char*) malloc(max_text_length*sizeof(char));
 tmp[1] = (char*) malloc(max_text_length*sizeof(char));
 tmp[2] = (char*) malloc(max_text_length*sizeof(char));

 tmp[0] = "some text";
 tmp[1] = "rand txt";
 tmp[2] = "text";

 int stridx[2*num_str];
 int *d_stridx;
 stridx[0] = 0;
 stridx[1] = 9;
 stridx[2] = 9;
 stridx[3] = 17;
 stridx[4] = 17;
 stridx[5] = 21;

 char *a, *d_a;
 a = (char *)malloc(num_str*max_text_length*sizeof(char));
 //flatten
 int subidx = 0;
 for(int i=0;i<num_str;i++)
 {
   for (int j=stridx[2*i]; j<stridx[2*i+1]; j++)
     a[j] = tmp[i][subidx++];
   subidx = 0;
 }

 cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a,num_str*max_text_length*sizeof(char));
 cudaMemcpy(d_a, a,num_str*max_text_length*sizeof(char),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
 cudaMalloc((void**)&d_stridx,num_str*2*sizeof(int));
 cudaMemcpy(d_stridx, stridx,2*num_str*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


 func<<<1,1>>>(d_a, d_stridx, num_str);
 cudaDeviceSynchronize();

}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o t389 t389.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t389
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
string[0]: some text
string[1]: rand txt
string[2]: text
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```